# Clarification of Map Scale

Tags: qgis, scale

I need some clarification. I have a map the is set to the scale of 1:6000. In *Settings>Project Properties*, under the General tab I have the Layer Units set to feet. Therfore I assume that means the scale is 1 foot equals 6000 feet. Does this seem rights? Or is it 1 inch equals 6000 inches?

I am ultimately attempting to convert this to traditional engineering scale of 1 inch equal __ feet.

---

Found this handy description for anyone that interested. http://groundwater.fullerton.edu/groundwater/Maps,_Scale,_GIS_and_GPS/Guide_to_Map_Scale.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the scale is a ratio, it doesn't have units itself. You can measure whatever you like on the map - one inch, one foot, one double-decker bus - and it will represent 6000 of the same unit in reality.

To give the scale in mixed units, you just have to know what 6000 inches are in feet - [OnlineConversion](http://www.onlineconversion.com/) tells me it's 500 feet - so you'd have 1 inch = 500 feet.